# Java Play2 - From session to cookie

Tags: java, session, authentication, cookies, playframework-2.0

**Update1:**

**Could you give me a short example on how to manage cookies and sessions in play2? (remember me function)**

Okay I think I understand the main concept behind the play authentication.

Zentasks uses sessions. I know that sessions are only stored on the server.
And sessions in play2 are already signed. Cookies are not.

What if the users wants to be logged in even if he closes the browser?

I would need to use a cookie.

What should I do?

Do I create a cookie that creates a session?

for example

- user has a valid cookie
- get cookie val and create a new session

Or do I completely discard sessions and only use cookies instead. Because cookies are not signed automatically by play2 , I have to do it by myself, which I did.

```
response().setCookie("remember",Crypto.sign(rnd) + "-" + obj.getClass().getName() + "-" + rnd,12000);
```

(I know I didn't make it secure yet with the secured and http only flag)

I just don't want to invent a new and flawed system. I hope you can clear things up for me how to make authentication secure in play2.

Comment: There's no place for "I'm sorries" ;) I edited your post. Now, explain please, what is that mean that 'user wants a cookie' ?

Comment: Why asking the user for technical implementation? Just make sure to create a working and responsive app! BTW sessions are always managed by cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398715/difference-between-creating-a-session-and-a-cookie

Comment: @biesior I edited my post. (user wants a cookie ?) -> (What if the users wants to be logged in even if he closes the browser?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me a lot

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~opensource21/permsec/trunk/view/head:/psec/app

Answer (score 3):

The [session scope](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaSessionFlash) in Play is nothing more than signed (secure) cookie (and they are stored on client's, **not** server's side!)

From above docs:

> It’s important to understand that Session and Flash data **are not**
>   stored in the server but are added to each subsequent HTTP Request,
>   using Cookies.

so you can keep the `logged in` state by checking if the `session scope's key`  exists and matches any of your user.

<s>*De facto* session scope doesn't expire automatically, so your user will be `logged in` until he'll click on the `logout` action link (in which you need just to destroy the session's key)</s> (only in some browsers)

Comment: okay thanks, but if I close the browser my session is gone. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @MaikKlein : did you check it? I just was testing, the session scope is available even after browser's closing and purging the whole memory. So you should rather worry, how to destroy it if needed ;)

Comment: really? I double checked it. I always lose the "cookie". I tried IE and chrome. I used the command -> play run

Comment: @MaikKlein : Really, really, check tjis simple test: https://github.com/biesior/test-play-session

Comment: Still gone. But I am currently on my linux laptop. Out of curiosity, I'll check your app on my pc.

Comment: Nope it's always gone after I close my browser. I am using play 2.0.2 updating to 2.0.3 now

Comment: Now I can see, that's dependent on the browser in OS X. will check this topic yet and will let you know if I will find some better conclusion

Comment: I agree with @biesior and your cookie should persist even if you close your browser.

Comment: Sorry @nico_ekito, apparently I made a mistake, documentation writes, that expiration time for Session scope is Session - which means, that  after browser's closing it *should* be destroyed. Unfortunately some browser on my Mac destroys it, other keeps the session even after app and browser restart. Mischmasch. I have no time to find the way how to make sure that session will be kept all destroyed. Busy time, I'll beck to this topic in next few days, I hope

Comment: Atm I am using a cookie to generate a valid session. But it doesn't feel right. :)

Comment: @MaikKlein I'm just siting and reading: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/JkXNz1mbvZE/9L_yOwfPmTcJ - Guillaume wrote there, that's the correct way :)

Comment: @biesior recent versions of chrome are keeping session cookies alive between sessions :( http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513

Comment: @biesor He says " For a "Remember Me", use your own cookie, not the session one. " Okay this means that I should only use cookies and no sessions. Damn I already got this yesterday now I have cookies + sessions.

Comment: Could you give me a short example on how to manage cookies and sessions in play2? (remember me function)